# possible to dynamically add objects to an array and have Vuejs detect it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

#### edit 2

I think the issue is how I'm referring to an array from a parent component. A fiddle is provided in the comments.

---

I have an app where we want to be able to add items to a menu_header. I have tried pushing to the bottom of the array but Vuejs doesn't seem to be detecting it.

I have read this section https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats and am trying to make this work but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Something like:

```
var obj = { name: "my name" }
menu_header.items.push(obj);
```

Do I need to use `this.$set` syntax? I really need to add into the middle of an array via splice.

#### edit 1

So this is a component that is recursive (ie a menu_header can have many menu_headers). I have tried adding a simple button in a menu_item to add to the parent component like this:

```
methods:{
  addItem: function(){
   var items = this.$parent.$data.menuHeader.menu_items;
   var obj = { header: "my header", detail: "this detail"}
    console.log("11 items length: " + items.length);
   items.splice(1,0,obj);
   console.log("22 items length: " + items.length);
  },
```

The count of the number of items is incremented but the view doesn't rerender. This component is nested 3 levels deep (a Menu component has many MenuHeader components which can have many MenuItem components and also have many MenuHeader components). I'm pretty sure it's a reactivity / array issue - but not sure about exact problem.

Comment: `push` should work fine. What does the data function look like?

Comment: ok - I've tried calling  `vm.$forceUpdate();` and `this.$forceUpdate();`; I can see it is being added via doing a length of items - Any other ideas to figure out what is going on? Sorry, first time using Vue and appreciate the help.

Comment: Post the component.

Comment: ok - let me try to make a simpler example later today.

Comment: @Bert I updated with a part that I think is causing problems. It's a large set of components so might have to post a simplified version of all of them working together (but running to meet friends now). Thx for any help.

Comment: I don't see the problem yet in the. albeit unusual, code post so far.

Comment: @Bert  I have the feeling that the "unusual code" (I assume you mean this.$parent.$data....) is the issue. I have gotten parts of it working and have included a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/trestles/pb9oc7n0/7/     - The basic issue is that when I click 'add item', it copies the last obj and appends it, rather than splicing a new item in the desired location (this is ~ line 58 in fiddle). Thanks for any help - definitely a newbie with Vuejs and appreciate it.

Comment: is `menu_header` available in `data`?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran I think so - I make a ref in line 82 of fiddle to set this.menuHeader = menu_header  - lmk if I've made some mistake (I'm assuming I have at this point).

Comment: Based on the migration [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Array-prototype-remove-removed), vue2.x will not detect the change when splice is used to add an element to the array

Comment: Just replace your splice with `items.push(myObj)`.

Comment: @Bert thx - well, I'm going to have to be splicing in the main app. Any idea if this can be fixed? I'm sure it's a problem on my understanding of Vuejs as having just started using it.

Comment: [Does this work correctly](https://jsfiddle.net/pb9oc7n0/9/)? If so, I'll explain in an answer.

Comment: @bert - thx - it looks like it! This is the first step - won't obviously be adding to fixed position. any info on my error / bug would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really the issue here was that [you should use a key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) with a list in order for Vue to property render it in all cases and when you are iterating over a component you *must* use a key. The code in the fiddle is properly adding the elements to the array and Vue is detecting the changes, it just doesn't properly render the list because of it's update strategy. Using a key fixes that.

To that end I modified these lines in the template.

```
<div v-for="menu_header in menu.menu_headers" :key="menu_header.name">
```

and

```
<div v-for="(menu_item, idx) in menuHeader.menu_items" :key="menu_item.header">
```

The best key for these is some unique property of the object in the list. The above uses `name` and `header`, but I expect with real code you could come up with a better key.

It's best to get in the habit of always adding a key whenever you render a list in Vue.

Comment: just want to thank you - this description is much clearer than the docs.

Comment: oh and if you want to tell me what is wrong with my vue code, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @timpone The biggest issue I see is the reference to $parent. Generally you do not want a component to reach out of itself. Idiomatically in Vue, you would emit the value. I'm not sure the Add Item button belongs in that component TBH. Probably the parent should have the Add Item button in the first place.

Comment: thx - duly noted - will try getting all pieces working and then refactor. appreciate the feedback.